# Iframe displayed without its content in sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, sharepoint-2013

I'm using javascript/jquery to add an iframe with content to an existing nintex form under sharepoint 2013:

```
$('<iframe name="myiframe" id="myiframe"><form target="myiframe" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="file" type="file" /> <input type="button" value="Upload"/> </form></iframe>').appendTo('body');
```

it works BUT the iframe is completely empty:

```
<iframe name="myiframe" id="myiframe">
    <html>
       <head></head>
       <body></body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

so my question is here: Am I doing something wrong there? OR is sharepoint the cause of this (and if so what can I do to work around this problem?)

Comment: iframe needs src to loadup documents if you need to show any document inside iframe then i suggest you to add the `src` attribute and give the url of your page which you want to loadin it. Its has to be something like: `<iframe name="myiframe" id="myiframe" src="pathtoyour/myform.aspx"></iframe>`.

Comment: ah so setting a content to an iframe manually wont work it always needs a source FILE ?